# jQuery Permission Denied when using AJAX in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

This one has me absolutely at wits end. For my site I am using ajax to replace the content of a DIV. Every other page will work fine in all browsers, however there are some links under my Portfolio tab that are not. They are "photography", "interactive", "print", and "traditional". When I try to click on those using IE8, they returned a "Permission Denied" in my jquery.js file on line 2, character 3238. The jQuery file has been updated to the latest version available. The only special attribute with these four pages is they have a pagination script and a shadowbox.js script. If I load those pages alone outside of AJAX, the code works fine. From my testing, the scripts work fine in everything else, minus slow speeds on the images but I will fix that later. If anyone has any solutions at all, it would be greatly appreciated. I tried answers from a few things around here but none of them have fixed this.

My site is located at http://codyshawdesign.com

Comment: It would be best if you post the relevant pieces of code for your question, rather than expect people to sift through your site's source code in a mad hunt.

Comment: probably a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079949/jquery-ajax-doesnt-trigger-in-internet-explorer

Comment: @Richard Neil Ilagan My apologies. I was unsure whether I should or not because I was unsure which js was causing the problem and figured a lengthy post would be looked down upon.

Comment: @rt2800 No my error message was slightly different.
At any rate it looks as if I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can quicky see, it is not relative to JQuery, but to the way you do your async requests.

This URL renders errors on IE: http://codyshawdesign.com/#traditional,

```
<script id=__ie_ondomload defer=true src=//:></script>
```

First of all, **correct your AJAX request**.

**Do not return a full HTML document** to insert it in your page. Only the content you need !

And because it is the same page, directly include your scripts and CSS in your index document.

All this **shouldn't be part of your AJAX response**!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Traditional</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init({
     counterType: 'skip',
}
    [......]
});    
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: I could not figure out where you were pulling this from...
'<script id=__ie_ondomload defer=true src=//:></script>'

But I stripped out the other HTML and put it into comment tags as a conditional statement for lower versions of IE. The reason I made them full statements was because I was attempting to make the site friendly for older IE users and those with javascript disabled, but at any rate it is fixed now. Thank you very much for your help!